# Read ISO/IEC 14443B (NFC Type B) with PN532

Tags: arduino-uno, rfid

I bought a [PN532 from Elechouse](http://www.elechouse.com/elechouse/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=90_93&products_id=2242) ([documentation here](http://www.elechouse.com/elechouse/images/product/PN532_module_V3/PN532_%20Manual_V3.pdf)) because I need to read IDs from `Type B` NFC cards.

My problem is that even if they say the hardware supports `Type B`, the official libraries an examples they provide are not made to.

I have not problem reading `Type A` cards, but nothing happends when I tap `Type B` cards.

After long searchs on internet I found that absolutely every `PN532` sellers have chosen to support only `Type A` cards in their libraries because according to them, a librari supporting both types would have taken too much space in Arduino's memory.

So today my problem is as simple as that: **how to read Type B NFC cards using PN532 on an Arduino UNO?**

I'm a bit new in Arduino so after many hours of searching and trying I couldn't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Same problem even using libnfc
doesn´t work with that card, only recognizes it
i read that it could be an antenna problem, because of the elechouse pn532.
I´m going to try to made an external antenna

Comment: We eventually gave up after many attempts, even involving other developpers, turned out the protocol was quite specific, in the end we used smartphones with NFC capability that could read it.

Answer (score 1):

I dont have an exact reply but

1) are you certain the other tags are type b?

2) hace you tried connecting the reader using a UART USB cable? You could use libnfc, to check if the reader works.
And going forward [at commands FOR the reader](http://www.nxp.com/documents/user_manual/141520.pdf) are a good way to debbug.